# jQuery Autocomplete doesn't work with custom object.

Tags: php, jquery

I'm sending an object from PHP that gets through perfectly, then I walk it with `.each` with jQuery, make a `console.log` and all seems fine, but when I assign the "com" object, it doesn't work...
Instead if I manually complete the com, by example, com=["dato1","dato2"], it works...

```
$(function() {

var URL= '../../controllers/region.controller.php';
        var dataf= 'accion=getCom';
        var com = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:dataf,
                    success:function(data){
                        var c = JSON.parse(data);
                        $.each(c, function(index, val) {
                           com.push(val.COM_NOM);  
                        });
                        $( "#com_nom" ).autocomplete({source:com});
                    }       
             });
});
```

Comment: Hi, We only allow Question in English, please translate it and update your answer.

Comment: I think you need to write this in your ajax  dataType: "json"